# Outlook 2010 Message Rules for Sending

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, rules

quite an interesting one regarding message rules...

I have some users who want to use message rules to filter an email **before it's sent** and then depending on which email addresses have been included in the To: field, if certain ones appear, to **stop** the message being sent and a message alert box to be displayed.

OS: Win7 & XP pro

Office (Outlook) 2010 & XP (2002)

I've looked through setting up message rules, but the rules seem to lack the ability to apply to a message before it is sent, rather it reads 'apply this rule after I send a message', any ideas/input? Thanks! :)

Comment: We have come up with a solution, but only with using VBA code as thims mentioned below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, Outlook's outgoing rules run just **before** message is sent. Do not be confused by "after I send a message", they mean "after I click Send button" by this.

Real question is how to stop messages from being sent... The only thing that comes to my mind is defer delivery. There is no out-of-the-box way to cancel delivery. You can write custom VBA script however.

Comment: Thanks! Will leave unanswered for the time being to see if there is an 'out of the box' way to cancel :)